# querying over multiple data from function in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function which gives stock levels:

```
select * from stocklevel(ID)
```

This function gives stock leverl per ID.
For example:

```
select * from stocklevel(23)
```

Result is:

```
   ID  datelevel  stocklevel
   23   01.01.17   15
   23   02.01.17   18
   23   05.01.17   20
```

This is the stock level for `ID=23`.

Not all dates appear, it depends on many things.

I want to use this function to get the stock levels for all parts from my system

basically something like this:

```
select *,(select stocklevel from stocklevel(parts.partid) where datelevel = ??? )
from parts
```

OR:

```
  select *
  from parts
  left join ( select stocklevel from stocklevel(parts.partid) where datelevel = ??? ) using (ID)
```

Now, the issue is with the `WHERE` condition I want to specific a specific date like '04.01.17' but if the date does not exist i want it to take the date before that so:

for the `ID=23` and date `'04.01.17'` it should show `18`,`'02.01.17'` .

for the `ID=23` and date `'15.01.13'` it should show nothing.

for the `ID=23` and date `'05.01.17'` it should show `20`,`'05.01.17'` .

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would use a `lateral` join:

```
select *
from parts p left join lateral
     stocklevel(p.partid);
```

Then the issue is that you want the most recent level before or on a given date.  You can do this using `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (p.id) . . .
from parts p left join lateral
     stocklevel(p.partid)
where datelevel <= ?
order by p.id, datelevel desc;
```

Note:  This will not return parts that have no dates before the given date.  You might want:

```
where datelevel is null or datelevel <= ?
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the note... datelevel is never null. If date was skipped it won't have a record.

Comment: @avi . . . I mean, if your date is earlier than any stock level for that part, then the part will not be returned.  The `NULL` comes from the outer join.

Comment: don't I need Using or On in the join?

Comment: @avi . . . Not with a lateral join (a good place to start is with the documentation:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
  from parts
  left join ( select stocklevel 
      from stocklevel(parts.partid) 
      where datelevel = (select max(datelevel) 
            from stocklevel(parts.partid) sl2 
            where sl2.datelevel <= '04.01.17') using(ID) ) using (ID)
```

untested...